# Are air gapped PCs sufficiently secure running XP?

Tags: windows-xp, security

I have several XP SP2 machines on a LAN and several XP SP3 machines standalone. All are air gapped from the internet and receive no patches or AV updates. File transfers are by burning CDs containing the needed data files only. Is this considered to be secure?

Comment: there was a new item that snowden uncovered that the US Govt was able to  spy on people by radio transmissions transceiver in USB cables.   http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/15/us/nsa-effort-pries-open-computers-not-connected-to-internet.html but "There is no evidence that the N.S.A. has implanted its software or used its radio frequency technology inside the United States."  so it is in foreign places.

Comment: Depends on how "secure" you need them to be.

Answer (score 3):

Secure from Internet threats sure.  You may or may not be concerned with physical threats (someone walking up and hacking it) or whether it will interface with other insecure devices (e.g. an infected USB drive).